# Go from AWS root to ec2-user

Tags: unix, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Using unix, I'm able to ssh successfully into my instance using the following:

```
 ssh -i ~/.ssh/seis_v3.pem root@52.5.233.876
```

However, when I try to login as ec2-user instead of root, I get denied.  Is there a way once in root@52.5.233.876 to change directory or permissions to get onto ec2-user?  Thank you.

Comment: Which AMI are you using? By default amazon Linux only allows you to access with ec2-user and not root. Third party AMI's may not even have ec2-user set up.

Comment: I have no AMI setup on the AWS EC2.  Is that something I should setup?

Comment: You would have used an AMI to launch your current instance. Which AMI did you use?

Comment: Unix, and I login with mac

Comment: What is the AMI ID of the instance you created?  If you log onto the instance and issue the command "curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ami-id/" (make sure to include that last / in the URL) it should return a string along the lines of ami-9d23aeea.

Comment: Here is the AMI ID: ami-728ace1a

Answer (score 3):

ami-728ace1a corresponds to the this AMI : suse-sles-11-sp3-sapcal-v20150127-hvm-mag-x86_64. It's an image for SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11.  I just launched an instance using this AMI and when I tried to ssh in as root:

```
$ ssh -i id_rsa root@54.158.122.xxx
Please login as the user "ec2-user" rather than the user "root".
```

So I tried to log in as the ec2-user:

```
$ ssh -i id_rsa ec2-user@54.158.122.xxx
Last login: Mon Apr 13 01:35:47 2015 from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP3 x86_64 (64-bit)
```

You mentioned being able to successfully log in as root.  Do you get the message that I got above? If not then are you sure you provided the correct AMI ID for this instance?  Did you make any changes to the root account and/or any other accounts on this system after launching it?  Do you see an ec2-user listed in /etc/passwd?

Comment: I do not believe I made any changes to the root account, but it's possible.  When I look into /etc/passwd, not ec2-user are listed.

Comment: Can you confirm that this instance is running SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11?

Comment: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP3